# VC-dimension of Hyper-rectangles

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, machine-learning

I have question about VC-dimension(Hyper-rectangles in Rn) = 2n

*Hyper-rectangle = [a1,b1]×[a2,b2]×⋯×[an,bn]*

I trying to prove that the VC-dimension for Hyper-rectangles of size n in Rn dimension, is 2d.

I trying to do with induction , but I not able to do it.

base case: n = 1 or n = 2,
for line(d=1), we can take to point in each interval, means VC-dimension = 2
same for rectangle in R2, VC-dimension =4.

I will assume that this is true for n-1.

but how I can do it for n dimension?

Comment: What is a VC-dim  ? Not a common abbreviation.

Comment: What is your definition of a hyper-rectangle ? A set $[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \times \cdots \times [a_n,b_n]$ ?

Comment: 1. sorry about that, fixed to VC-dimension. 2. yes, sorry for that.

Comment: I still don't see the **definition** of VC dimension. Besides, what is the meaning of the "V" and the "C" ?

Comment: Having no answer from you, I went to google and obtained this [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension).